# What's the difference between the two abstract data types collection vs container?

Tags: data-structures, abstract-data-types

From abstract data types in wiki, I'm reading about two types: **collection** and **container**. Can anyone supply a better detailed difference between the difference between the two?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Container_(abstract_data_type)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collection_(abstract_data_type)

As I understand...

**Collection** is an abstract data type.

- it is a grouping of some variable number of data items. Collections can be further specialized into Linear Collections, Associative Collections, and Graph Collection.
- "Collection does not prescribe a specific implementation as a concrete data structure, though often there is a conventional choice (see Container ) "

**Container** is an abstract data type.

- they store objects in an organized way that follows specific access rules.
- seem to have more explicit properties/methods i.e CRUD operators, etc.

From what it looks like, Collection is definitely more abstract compared to containers. Collection seem to define a general relation on the insides of how data are related to each other in order/or lack there of. The container ADT is also very similar, but I'm guessing container is just a slightly more detail abstraction for defining what essential operations is needed so that almost all lower more specific ADT can be implemented using containers.

side note: "Collection does not prescribe a specific implementation as a concrete data structure, though often there is a conventional choice (see Container ) " - then what is not a conventional choice?

Comment: In my understanding, a container is the supporting data structure and the collection is the set of contained elements. They are equally "abstract" concepts.

Comment: @YvesDaoust thx ! but what does it mean as a supporting data structure?